# Delaunay-based isosurface extraction vs marching cubes

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh-generation

I recently tried the isosurface extraction algorithm provided by the C++ library **CGAL**. This is new to me. It is based on Delaunay triangulations.

I have some experience with the marching cubes, I tried to compare these two methods but it  is not easy to conclude. Regarding the speed, I have the impression that there's no winner, each method can beat the other, depending on the case. For example, the marching cubes algorithm is undoubtly faster for the trihyperboloid:

[image]

Regarding the quality of the mesh, I didn't observe some difference. I'm wondering whether there exist some examples for which the Delaunay-based method is better than the marching cubes. Would you know such examples? The Delaunay-based method has three input parameters (three bounds, an angle, a distance and a radius), while the marching cubes only requires the choice of a grid. So I believe it's possible that the Delaunay-based method can achieve something better in some cases.